# How to use SunMSCAPI key to decrypt RSA-OAEP

Tags: java, windows, encryption, rsa

I have a certificate with private key stored in windows certificate store. How can I use this key to decrypt a message that uses OAEP padding? I am able to decrypt the message using Bouncycastle provider and pfx file (PKCS12 keystore), but not windows store (SunMSCAPI).

I am using basically this code

```
KeyStore keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keyStore.load(null, null);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("keyalias", null);

java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

JceKeyTransRecipient jceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey);
CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData = new CMSEnvelopedData(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedData));
RecipientInformationStore recipientInfos = envelopedData.getRecipientInfos();
RecipientInformation recipient = recipientInfos.getRecipients().iterator().next();
byte[] decrypted = recipient.getContent(jceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient);
```

and it results into

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:892)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1248)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1185)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JceAsymmetricKeyUnwrapper.generateUnwrappedKey(JceAsymmetricKeyUnwrapper.java:148)
```

If I specify the provider like this:

```
JceKeyTransRecipient jceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient = new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(privateKey).setProvider("SunMSCAPI");
```

Then I get error (OAEP not supported)

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.7
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:687)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:595)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.util.NamedJcaJceHelper.createCipher(NamedJcaJceHelper.java:47)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createAsymmetricWrapper(OperatorHelper.java:267)
```

Shortly, java doesn't support OAEP, and even though BC does support OAEP, it cannot use it for "external" keys. If that is true, are there other options?

Comment: SunMSCAPI doesn't support OAEP. So either stop using SunMSCAPI or stop using OAEP.

Comment: Sadly, encryption is being done by other party, no way to change it. And we need to consider that the user keys will be on a smartcard, no way to export them to a file (which is bad idea anyway).

Comment: Then (1) don't use Java or (2) since Java is opensource, fork it and modify it as you need. Since cryptoproviders are isolated by the JCA design, this is only a big difficult job not a massively giant huge impossible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think James is [correct with his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088372/how-to-use-sunmscapi-key-to-decrypt-rsa-oaep#comment104412574_59088372). It is just that the `SunMSCAPI` bridge [doesn't support OAEP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/security/oracle-providers.html#GUID-4F1737D6-1569-4340-B140-678C70E63CD5), even if the Windows platform does. `SunMSCAPI` will not release the private key value, so what happens is that Java will search any provider that supports OAEP **and** the private key object, and then cannot find any. This explains the initial exception: `No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey`.

Note that the statement "Java doesn't support OAEP" is clearly false as OAEP is [even included as required algorithm](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#security-algorithm-implementation-requirements). In other words, without OAEP you cannot even *call it Java*, and in fact the SunJCE provider does include support for it, including support for more hash functions and other bit sizes than just 1024 and 2048 bits. However, that does require a key that is compatible with the software implementation.

Comment: There is no SunRSA provider; SunRsaSign only does signature and is effectively obsolete. It is **SunJCE** that supports it under the Java 'transform' name `RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding` -- but **not by OID**; BCprov does both name and OID. And BCpkix `OperatorHelper` maps _most_ OIDs (from CMS RecipientInfo or SignerInfo) to the Java-style names, but not ..113549.1.1.7 for rsaOaep, thus `createCipher` tries to use the OID. But net, yes, even with the name SunMSCAPI doesn't support it -- although since 11 it does support RSASSA-PSS signature! (Perhaps because TLS1.3?)

Comment: Probably, almost everything in Java security is TLS related. I'll change to SunJCE, should have checked.